# Create a client server relation ms-access

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on an access application in local.
I'd like to use this application on a local network on differents computers.
I heard that I could create a client side application and a server side access application, the clients are connected to the server just giving the server path to the client but I don't find how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to split the database into a Front End and a Back End.  You can do this manually, although there is actually a wizard within Access that will do it as well.  The result is basically a "back end" with all the tables, and a "front end" with everything else (queries, forms, reports, macros and modules).  All you have to do is link the tables in the back end to the front end, the same way you would link to any external data whether it be Access, SQL Server or  what have you.

You can then distribute the front end to all your users, leaving your back end on a network.  Just make sure you **never** move your back end, or your distributed front ends will not know where to find the data.